# Error "redirect_uri_mismatch" when using Google OAuth2 in Python

Tags: python, google-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to use Google OAuth2 in Python to upload videos to YouTube using the YouTube Data API. However, I'm getting an "redirect_uri_mismatch" error when I try to authenticate the user. Here's my code:

```
import pickle
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
import google_auth_oauthlib
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
import os

# credentials
CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE = "client_secret.json"
YOUTUBE_UPLOAD_SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth2/youtube.upload"
YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME = "youtube"
YOUTUBE_API_VERSION = "v3"

def get_authenticated_service():
    credentials = None
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            credentials = Credentials.from_authorized_user_info(info=pickle.load(token))
    if not credentials or not credentials.valid:
        flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE, [YOUTUBE_UPLOAD_SCOPE])
        credentials = flow.run_local_server(port=8080)
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(credentials.to_authorized_user_info(), token)
    return build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION, credentials=credentials)

def upload_to_youtube(video_path, title, description):
    try:
        youtube = get_authenticated_service()

        # Create the MediaFileUpload object for the video
        media = MediaFileUpload(video_path, chunksize=-1, resumable=True)

        # Create the video on YouTube
        video = youtube.videos().insert(
            part="snippet,status",
            body={
                "snippet": {
                    "title": title,
                    "description": description,
                },
                "status": {
                    "privacyStatus": "private",
                },
            },
            media_body=media,
        ).execute()

        print(f'Uploaded video: {video["id"]}')

    except HttpError as e:
        print(f'An error occurred: {e}')
        return False
    return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    video_path = "test.mp4"
    title = "My video title"
    description = "My video description"
    upload_to_youtube(video_path, title, description)
```

And here's the error message I'm getting:

[image]

I've checked the redirect URI in both my code and the Google Cloud Console and they match. I've also tried generating a new client ID and secret and updating my code, but the error still persists.

What could be causing this error and how can I fix it? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: click the second link in the image and post that please

Comment: ok i will do that